# Getting session information from within an iframe

Tags: session, iframe, session-state

I have a site that uses the database for storing its session data.  on this site I have a link which opens a page that contains an iframe in it.  Inside the iframe I have a 3rd party app that is using its own session information for login, etc.

When I am inside the 3rd party app I want to be able to access the $_SESSION information from my own site's db session, but when I do a var_dump to check out the $_SESSION, I only get the 3rd party app's session information and not my site's.

I'm not wanting to touch the code for the 3rd party app that handles the session, for the fear of breaking the 3rd party app, so if there is a way to get to my sites $_session info without touching the 3rd party session configuration that's what I'm hoping to accomplish.

Is it possible to do this?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are the two sites hosted on the same domain?

Comment: Yes, the folder structure is www.mydomain.com/admin/mysite/3rd party files